# Connect to MySQLi through a specific IP

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, mysqli

Due to a network outage, our architecture changed for a week or two. Now I am required to have 2 IPs in the network, one with 192.168.1.* and the second with 192.168.2.* .

The web development server where the mysql databases are located is accesible only from the 192.168.2.* IP.

Because of that, mySQLi connection takes exactly 20 seconds which is unacceptable :D

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$link = mysqli_init();

if (!mysqli_options($link, MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 3)) {
    die('Setting MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT failed');
}
mysqli_real_connect($link, $_env[$ENVIRONMENT]['host'], $_env[$ENVIRONMENT]['user'], $_env[$ENVIRONMENT]['pass'], $_env[$ENVIRONMENT]['db'], 3306) or die("Could not connect: ".mysqli_error($link));
```

Setting a connect timeout of 3 seconds does not resolve the problem. How should I fix this?

(I use Windows)

Comment: Sounds like a problem that is solved by setting correct ip routes.

Comment: Yeah, seems so. Then the main question is there is no way that I can tell the MySQLi driver to connect to a host through a specific IP?

Comment: Have you tried binding the apache process to a specific IP? That's the only thing I can think of, haven't tested it though.

Comment: Please clarify; both the Web server and the MySQL database are in the same 192.168.2.* network. Still, the mySQLi connection from the web Server to the database takes 20 seconds?

Comment: @kums Yes, the apache is on the 192.168.2.* but is also on the 192.168.1.* network (I have 2 ips). I think it tries to use the 1.* network, fails after 20 secs and then uses the 2.* network and succeedes.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks; I've tried it and it doesn't change the situation. Damn...